# I can still see my website live even though i have shut it down

Tags: vps, digital-ocean, forever

I created a droplet in digital ocean and hosted my sails.js website/App. I made changes to the website but it didn't reflect(The website shows the old stuff). Now i stopped the website by running `forever stopAll app.js` when i do `forever list` I get **info: No forever processes running** confirming that all processes have stopped. But i can still see the website live. I have enough memory and disk space.

I cleared my memory with `sync; sudo echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` following this: http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1204033 but i can still see the old stuffs.

cleared my browser history but nothing worked for me. what could be the problem please. thanks in advance

Comment: what's the domain ?

Comment: try the forever list with sudo

Comment: Thanks the problem was solved. I just deleted the **.tmp**  folder in my sails app, executed `forever run` and its working now